# docker-runc not installed on system

Tags: docker, centos7, yum

I recently updated my Centos 7 based machine. And since, i fail to start any of my dockers. Does someone have some experience with this issue and if yes how did you fix it ?
Thanks for your valuable help.
Below the error log

docker run -it centos6_labs_ompi161_devtools3
/usr/bin/docker-current: Error response from daemon: shim error: docker-runc not installed on system.

Comment: See https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/26022

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It seems that the docker rpm misses some symbolic link in the end.
As it was pointed to me, this issue was raised on:

```
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2876431
```

and this can be easily fixed by:

```
cd /usr/libexec/docker/
sudo ln -s docker-runc-current docker-runc
```

Comment: Above solution doesn't solve my issue, i am using centos 7.0

Comment: Don't forget to include /usr/libexec/docker in the path when starting dockerd. (The link solution works for me using centos 7.4)

Comment: Above solution did  work for me on centos 7  but forcefully killed docker and started. Kill Docker
ps axf | grep docker | grep -v grep | awk '{print "kill -9 " $1}' | sudo sh start docker
sudo systemctl start docker

Comment: This works for my case. my docker version 1.13.1 and Centos 7

Answer (score 37):

In reference to the top answer, introduce the sym link in /usr/bin to enable it in global path

```
sudo ln -s /usr/libexec/docker/docker-runc-current /usr/bin/docker-runc
```

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: Works on CentOS7

Comment: This answer worked for me, where NabilG's did not.  On centos 7, with Docker 1.12.6. 
 Thank you!

Comment: Worked for me on redhat7

Answer (score 4):

I know that this is a rather old question; however, this occured when I updated from CentOS - Extras docker to Docker's own docker-ce rpm.  The service file located at /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service had the following lines hardcoded into the ExecStart line:

```
--add-runtime docker-runc=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-runc-current \
--default-runtime=docker-runc \
--exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=systemd \
--userland-proxy-path=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-proxy-current \
```

By default, the docker-ce package does not come with the same set of lines and the file paths are different.  After upgrading I added the following and the containers respected my start commands with no data lost as expected:

```
 --add-runtime docker-runc=/usr/bin/docker-runc \
    --default-runtime=docker-runc \
    --exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=systemd \
    --userland-proxy-path=/usr/bin/docker-proxy
```

Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 4):

Please try this

Failure shim error: docker-runc not installed on system

```
cd /usr/libexec/docker/
cp docker-runc-current /usr/bin/docker-runc
```

Answer (score 1):

Not CentOS related but for Slackware I had to install a separate `runc` package.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Nabil Ghodbane's method, but it didn't work.
Thanks to billabongrob's answer, I found a way to fix this problem.
You can try this Docker config file:

```
$ cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
    "log-level":"warn",
    "hosts": ["unix:///var/run/docker.sock","tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"],
    "runtimes": {
        "docker-runc": {
            "path": "/usr/libexec/docker/docker-runc-current"
        }
    },
    "add-runtime": "docker-runc=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-runc-current",
    "default-runtime": "docker-runc"
}
```

or use this config in your command line .