# How can I save a docker plugin to file so that I can install it on a machine without internet

Tags: docker, plugins, offline

I am using Docker to deploy my application as Docker containers.

In one of the containers I use a volume that uses the vieux/sshfs plugin.
I can install and use the plugin using
`docker plugin install vieux/sshfs`
on a computer that has access to the internet.

However, I am deploying the container to a computer on a closed network.
On that computer it is not possible to access docker hub as required by this command.
I am therefore looking for a way to save the plugin to a file, transfer the file to the target computer and install it on that computer from the file.

I use a similar approach for images.
I save them on one computer and load them from file on the target.

Is there any way to do the same for plugins?

If not, is there another method which will enable me to install Docker plugins without access to the internet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

definitely you can install vieux/sshfs offline.
First install this plugin on any machine having internet and go to "/var/lib/docker/plugins/" directory.
Copy plugin directory to the desired server for offline installation.

```
scp -prv 5e5c669384b43e6f74ac01c652969f1c706557dd243ff2e0701f7fbfdf8fc0e1 root@172.17.19.151:/var/lib/docker/plugins/
```

On the destination server

```
systemctl restart docker
docker plugin ls
ID                  NAME                 DESCRIPTION               ENABLED
5e5c669384b4        vieux/sshfs:latest   sshFS plugin for Docker   true
```

Comment: I am reopening this because it does not work as expected. Indeed the 'docker plugin ls' command shows the plugin is enabled however it does not work.
The simplest way to see the failure is as follows. When I run "docker volume ls" after running 'docker plugin ls' I expect to see an empty list. Instead I get an error 'Cannot connect to the Docker daemon... etc'. It looks like the plugin is crashing docker. https://stackoverflow.com/users/9121788/mayur-murkya, https://stackoverflow.com/users/1839439/dharman

Comment: ```[root@cloud-test ~]# docker plugin ls
ID                  NAME                 DESCRIPTION               ENABLED
5e5c669384b4        vieux/sshfs:latest   sshFS plugin for Docker   true
[root@cloud-test ~]#
[root@cloud-test ~]# docker volume ls|grep sshfs
vieux/sshfs:latest   sshvolume
[root@cloud-test ~]#
```

Comment: It worked for me when the target was an Ubuntu system (that happened to be connected to the internet - I don't know if that;s relevant). But when the target was a Red Hat system I got the error I reported above on "docker volume ls". When I looked at the logs in "systemctl status -l docker" I saw this error: "failed to enable plugin 'viewux-sshfs/latest": rpc error code = 2 desc = shim error: docker-runc not installed on system" 
Could this be because I copied the plugin from an installation of docker  on Ubunto which is a different distro than on the target machine?
@mayur murkya

Comment: I have accepted the answer again, because I found a resolution for the problem I was reporting in the comments. From this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42754779/docker-runc-not-installed-on-system I took this part and it solved the errors for me.
cd /usr/libexec/docker/
sudo ln -s docker-runc-current docker-runc
The plugin is now working and I can create a volume using it!